# How do I use Apache Camel's Spring Remoting Proxy with XML as the transport?

Tags: spring, jaxb, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel's Spring Remoting, version 2.11.0.  I have the following in my beans.xml:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:dataFormats>
        <camel:jaxb contextPath="path.to.my.jaxb.index"/>
    </camel:dataFormats>
</camel:camelContext>

<camel:proxy
    id="myProxy"
    serviceInterface="path.to.my.service.MyService"
    serviceUrl="jms:queue:myQueue" camelContextId="camel-client"/>
```

By default, camel:proxy uses object serialization, but I would like to use JAXB instead.  Is this possible? I have this pattern working over JAXB with ProducerTemplate, but when I switch to using camel:proxy, I get a NotSerializableException.

The producer template is created via the camel:camelContext tag and is injected via Spring:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"beans.xml"})
public class MyTest extends AbstractJunit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;  // this comes from <camel:camelContext>
    @Autowired MyService myService;  // this comes from <camel:proxy>

    @Test
    public void testMyService() {
        MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();

        // This correctly performs the JAXB serialization
        MyResponse response = producerTemplate.requestBody("jms:queue:myQueue", myRequest, MyResponse.class);

        // This still does Object serialization (and fails accordingly)
        response = myService.getResponse(myRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you create the ProducerTemplate?